# Broadcast new user android wifi hotspot

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I tried to find the user macaddress who are attempted to use my wifi hotspot in android in broadcast receiver.But Receiver not working when some one login my wifi .How can i find that

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver"> 
                    <intent-filter android:priority="100"> 
                        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"></action>
                         <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"></action>
                          <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE"></action>
                          <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"></action> <intent-filter>
```